# Find multiple string positions in PHP

Tags: php, string

I`m writing a PHP page that parses given URL. What I can do is find the first occurrence only, yet when I echo it, I get another value rather than the given.

this is what I did till now.

```
<?php
$URL = @"my URL goes here";//get from database
$str = file_get_contents($URL);
$toFind = "string to find";
$pos = strpos(htmlspecialchars($str),$toFind);
echo substr($str,$pos,strlen($toFind)) . "<br />";
$offset = $offset + strlen($toFind);
?>
```

I know that a loop can be used, yet I don`t know the condition neither the body of the loop would be.

And how can I show the output I need??

Comment: I don't know what exactly you want with this code, but it seems unclear to me what variable you wish to get on with. At this moment, you are supposed to echo exactly the contents of $toFind, so why not echo $toFind when a match is found? Or is $pos of too much importance to you? The issue however seems to originate from the htmlspecialchars() function, that might increase the length and layout of the original string. If you want to display the matched text, make sure you use it on the substr line as well.

Comment: @Pelle ten Cate: as you can see, the answer that was sent by codaddict was the same as yours. And I don`t just want to echo $toFind, because I will use the position found to get some content after the one I find.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This happens because you are using `strpos` on the `htmlspecialchars($str)` but you are using `substr` on `$str`.

`htmlspecialchars()` converts special characters to HTML entities. Take a small example:

```
// search 'foo' in '&foobar'

$str = "&foobar";
$toFind = "foo";

// htmlspecialchars($str) gives you "&amp;foobar"
// as & is replaced by &amp;. strpos returns 5
$pos = strpos(htmlspecialchars($str),$toFind);

// now your try and extract 3 char starting at index 5!!! in the original
// string even though its 'foo' starts at index 1.
echo substr($str,$pos,strlen($toFind)); // prints ar
```

To fix this use the same *haystack* in both the functions.

To answer you other question of finding all the occurrences of one string in other, you can make use of the 3rd argument of [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), offset, which specifies where to search from. Example:

```
$str = "&foobar&foobaz";
$toFind = "foo";
$start = 0;
while(($pos = strpos(($str),$toFind,$start)) !== false) {
        echo 'Found '.$toFind.' at position '.$pos."\n";
        $start = $pos+1; // start searching from next position.
}
```

Output:

> Found foo at position 1
> Found foo at position 8

Comment: To elaborate a little, htmlspecialchars replaces some characters with several new ones, which means you can't use the same indexes in both strings and expect the same result.

Comment: This solved one problem which is the output. But what about the other problem?

Comment: If foo is found at position 0 then the program will not even enter the loop. Should use `is_numeric($pos = strpos(($str),$toFind,$start))`

Comment: My bad confused `!==` with `!=`. The code works correctly. Thanks.

Comment: this code returns infinite output: "Found foo at position 1". what am i doing wrong?

Comment: This creates an infinite loop in php 5.6.10.
Need to add parens like this:
`while(($pos = strpos($str,$toFind,$start)) !== false)`

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
while( ($pos = strpos(($str),$toFind,$start)) != false) {
```

Explenation:
Set `)` after false behind `$start)`, so that `$pos = strpos(($str),$toFind,$start)` is placed between `()`.

Also use `!= false`, because php.net says:
'This function may return Boolean `FALSE`, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to `FALSE`, such as `0` or `""`. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the `===` operator for testing the return value of this function.

Comment: This is the only one that didn't create an infinite loop

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = '\n;alskdjf;lkdsajf;lkjdsaf \n hey judeee \n';
$pattern = '\n';
$start = 0;
while(($newLine = strpos($string, $pattern, $start)) !== false){
    $start = $newLine + 1;
    echo $newLine . '<br>';
}
```

This works out of the gate, and doesn't run an infinite loop like the above, and the !== allows for a match at position 0.

Comment: Agreed, the accepted answer above almost nails the problem but $pos is always TRUE which evalutes to 1 when printed out, leading to an infinite loop...thanks @user1371910 & marco

Answer (score 1):

```php
$offset=0;
$find="is";
$find_length=  strlen($find);
$string="This is an example string, and it is an example";
while ($string_position = strpos($string, $find, $offset)) {
    echo '<strong>'.$find.'</strong>'.' Found at '.$string_position.'</br>';
    $offset=$string_position+$find_length;
}
```